# Is "response" in this code an arbitrary placeholder argument of the jQuery success function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm giving my first steps in jQuery AJAX and had some questions. Kindly take a look at this code (which is part of a tutorial):

```
$.ajax("confirmation.html", {
    success: function(response) {
        $(".ticket").html(response).slideDown();
    }
};
```

I'm aware ajax() is a jQuery method. I know it takes a url and settings as its two parameters. I also understand what success does and what are its three expected parameters. Overall I understand what this code does: it gets that html and places it into the .ticket class. What I don't understand is:

1) What is that response argument inside of the success function? I'm assuming is the data returned by the server as explained in the official jQuery documentation. If that's correct then I guess any kind of name would have served this purpose, "response" being nothing but a placeholder. Hope I got that right.
And,

2) I hope this is correct: The HTML method will replace the content of the "ticket" class by the data, named as "(response)" in this case. So "response" here is again a reference to the placeholder argument passed to the success function.

Comment: You already answered your own question, inside the question... *confused*. I guess the answer is... Yes?

Comment: The success handler is just a function, with a parameter, same as any other function with a parameter.

Comment: `success` is a callback function.  It's called *by jQuery* with 3 parameters: the data, the status, and the jqXHR object.  You can name the parameters to that function whatever you like.

Comment: Thanks. I think I got it now. So if you only set one argument that's the data, the other two being optional I assume.

Comment: All parameters are *optional* in JavaScript.  You don't have to name any of them.  It's just the *de facto* standard to just set the 1st and ignore the others (in the case of ajax success).  You can still access the others via `arguments`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat why not convert your comment to an answer so that it can be accepted and the question can be resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`success` wants a callback function.  You can pass it whatever function you want.  jQuery will call it with 3 parameters when the AJAX call is done:

```
( PlainObject data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR )
```

In JavaScript, all parameters are *optional*.  You don't have to name any of them.  It's just the *de facto* standard with AJAX callbacks to just name the response parameter and ignore the others.